# how to display all category in magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

i am new in magento developer i am install magento in my domain but now I am displaying all the categories in home page but it is displaying only the top level categories. I want to display all the categories.

Answer (score 7):

Get category and subcategory:

```
<?php 
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
if (count($_categories) > 0){
    foreach($_categories as $_category){
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
        if (count($_subcategories) > 0){
            echo $_category->getName();
            echo $_category->getId();      
            foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory){
                 echo $_subcategory->getName();
                 echo $_subcategory->getId();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

To get only one category: (put category Id as we want)

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);
$subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
if (count($subcategories) > 0){
    echo $category->getName();
    foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
        echo $subcategory->getName();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below collection for display all categories. this code fetch data from catch.

```
$categoriesCollection = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, false);
```

Comment: where i put this code in my file i have no idea about that

Comment: Check in static page there available home page in that you can call your `.phtml` file and in you `.phml` file you can write this code and you can `print_r` whole collection.

Comment: you haven't even defined `$helper`